# How to block USB storage?

Tags: usb-drive

How to block or prevent USB storage mount automatically?
i have tried using this code, but doesn't work.

I have tried using this code, but it doesn't work.

```
sudo echo "blacklist usb-storage" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: You might have to give us some more information. What version of elementary are you using? Have you installed Nautilus? USB Media does not automatically mount on insertion for me in pantheon-files. Only once I click on the drive in the side bar.

Comment: Another thought, the command you gave would require an underscore rather than a hyphen in the module name. eg `usb_storage`

Comment: i tried that too.

Comment: @RayhanHuda, I flaged this as too board. You need to add more details to your question, `uname -a` ,  `lsb_release -r`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately elementary OS doesn't povide an UI to change this kind of options directly.

You need to install and run `dconf-editor` from the official repositories, navigate to *org -> gnome -> desktop -> media-handling*. Disable the options *automount-open* and *automount*, that should do the trick.

[image: dconf-edit]

Comment: These settings are for Nautilus, they don't affect Files. In fact, OP still hasn't specified which file manager he's using.